# Density of a set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space. We know by definition $A$ is dense in $X$ if $ \overline{A} = X $.

My question is. IS it enough that $\overline{A}  \subseteq X$ to say that $A$ is dense in $X$ ??

Comment: It is always true that $\overline{A} \subset X$...

Comment: If that were enough, then the empty set would always be dense. The relevant inclusion is that $\overline A\supseteq X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $X=[0,2]$ and $A=[0,1]$. Then $A= \overline{A} \subset X$, but  clearly $A$ is not dense in $X$ (for example, $(1,2) \subset X\setminus A$).